# sort function not sorting

Tags: c++, sorting

I'm very new to C++ and my question may sound silly but i'm working on a sort function using vectors.

the code is able to compile and run but it's just not sorting. may I know the reason why?

missionplan.cpp

```
bool MissionPlan::sortByCiv(const PointTwoD &t1, const PointTwoD &t2)
{
    return t1.locationdata.getCivIndex() > t2.locationdata.getCivIndex();
}

void MissionPlan::topfives()
{   
    topfive.assign( point1.begin(), point1.end() ); 
    sort(topfive.begin(), topfive.end(), sortByCiv);
    for(int i=0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        topfive.at(i).displayPointdata();
    }
}
```

pointtwod.h

```
class PointTwoD
{
    private:
        int xcord,ycord;
        float civIndex;
        //LocationData locationdata;

    public:
        PointTwoD();

        PointTwoD(int, int, float);


        string toString();
        void setPointDetail(int x, int y, float civ);
        void displayPointdata();
        void storedata(int, int, float);

        //set/mutator function
        void setxcord(int);
        void setycord(int);

        //get/accessor function
        int getxcord();
        int getycord();
        float getcivIndex();

        LocationData locationdata;


};
```

Locationdata.h

```
class LocationData
{
  private:
    string sunType;
    int noOfEarthLikePlanets, noOfEarthLikeMoons;
    float aveParticulateDensity, avePlasmaDensity;
    static float civIndex;

  public:
    LocationData(); //default constructor

    LocationData(string, int, int, float, float); // no default constructor
    void setLocationData(string, int, int, float, float);
    void displaydata();
    string toString();

    //'set' mustator function
    void setsunType(string);
    void setnoOfEarthLikePlanets(int);
    void setnoOfEarthLikeMoons(int);
    void setaveParticulateDensity(float);
    void setavePlasmaDensity(float);

    //'get' accessor function
    string getsunType();
    int getnoOfEarthLikePlanets();
    int getnoOfEarthLikeMoons();
    float getaveParticulateDensity();
    float getavePlasmaDensity();
    static float getCivIndex();

    static float computeCivIndex(string st, int earth, int moons, float particle, float plasma);

};
```

I've got another question.. 
    bool myfunction (int i,int j) { return (i

the result I'm expecting

```
X: 4  Y: 9 CIV: 10
X: 1  Y: 2 CIV: 5
X: 5  Y: 4 CIV: 4
X: 6  Y: 1 CIV: 3
X: 10 Y: 6 CIV: 1
```

and the result i receive from my prog, it's exactly the same seq as how i input them.

```
X: 10 Y: 6 CIV: 1
X: 5  Y: 4 CIV: 4
X: 4  Y: 9 CIV: 10
X: 1  Y: 2 CIV: 5
X: 6  Y: 1 CIV: 3
X: 5  Y: 9 CIV: 8
```

Comment: Why the sort is inside the `for` loop? It is enough to sort once and display the first 5 values.

Comment: Why are you sorting it `5` times?

Comment: "but it's just not sorting". How? What are you expecting and how does the result differ?

Comment: @AlexandruBarbarosie I've tried taking it out of the for loop but the value just won't get sorted

Comment: Are you sure std::sort is being called?

Comment: Your actual printout is 6 lines, but your for loop only executes 5 times. Are you sure your output is from this function?

Comment: If you're only interested in the "top N" (in this case 5) items in your container, [`std::partial_sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sort) will do it for you (and in fact that is precisely what it was designed for).

Comment: @AbhishekBansal http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/assign/

Comment: @Adam sorry wasn't aware of it.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal assign is actually a duplication of one vector of the other http://ww2.cs.mu.oz.au/acmicpc/www.cppreference.com/cppvector/all.html

the value of the CIV is from the locationdata class and my const should be LocationData instead of PointTwoD?

Comment: @koi_s3ng is there any chance you can post the actual class definition of `locationdata`, and in particular whatever `getCivIndex()` returns ? (update the question; don't post it here in-comment). Thanks. I have a suspicion about its members.

Comment: @WhozCraig hi, I've already update the question.. could you help me take a look at it?

Comment: Um.. yeah. Your sorting criteria is based on a static class member (the *same* static class member) for *all* class instances. as far as the sorting algorithm is concerned, all your elements are the same. `civIndex` is a single variable static to the class (and thus singularly shared by all instances of said-class). It is not per-instance.

Comment: @WhozCraig sorry I still don't really understand why it's not working? Do i have to change all my "civIndex" static. Cos "const PointTwoD &t1, const PointTwoD &t2" PointTwoD is refering to the datatype of my vector and I'm telling it to grab the value from the locationdata class..

Comment: @koi_s3ng thats exactly what you're doing, and its wrong. The "value" from the `LocationData` class is the same *single* value for *all* instances of `LocationData`, including all the instances that are member variables of your PointTwoD class.

Answer (score 2):

Unless I'm severely reading your code incorrectly, you are calling the wrong `getCivIndex()`. The one you're calling is using a static class variable. This means ALL instances of `LocationData` (including the internal instances in your `PostTwoD` objects), share the **same** static variable, and therefore have the same identical values. In other words, your comparator always returns *false* because N > N is never true. And thus your sort simply doesn't work.

I believe you want be using the `getcivIndex()` instance member of `PointTwoD`; not the static class member of `LocationData`

Several things should change for this to be "fixed"

First, change this:

```
float getcivIndex();
```

To this: (reasons will be apparent in a minute)

```
float getcivIndex() const;
```

You will also have to change the implementation of this function, wherever it is, to add `const` to its definition as well.

Next, change this:

```
bool MissionPlan::sortByCiv(const PointTwoD &t1, const PointTwoD &t2)
{
    return t1.locationdata.getCivIndex() > t2.locationdata.getCivIndex();
}
```

To this:

```
bool MissionPlan::sortByCiv(const PointTwoD &t1, const PointTwoD &t2)
{
    // use object instance-member. note: this is why getcivIndex()
    //  had to be made const. The t1 and t2 objects are const and as
    //  such only const-member-functions are callable.
    return t1.getcivIndex() > t2.getcivIndex();
}
```

And I suggest you see my comment about using `std::partial_sort` rather than a full-blown sort if all you want is the "top N" results in a sequence.

Comment: Thanks, it now works.. But I have another dumb question. The reason why we have const is so the the "value" won't be altered or get affected by the other memeber of the class?

Comment: @koi_s3ng not a dumb question. its a little more complicated than that, but you're close enough. `const` usage has some solid answers, and Meyers has a very good discussion in Effective C++. You have the right idea though.